# Linq-To-Entities subquery with string concatenation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to convert a SQL query I've written into an equivalent Linq-To-Entities query. It's got a subquery that concatenates a couple fields together which is then used as the field I need to join on.

SQL:

```
select distinct ta.Filename
from TableA ta 
inner join ( 
    SELECT distinct isnull(tb.StringField,convert(varchar,tc.IntField) + convert(varchar,tb.IntFieldB)) as NewNames
        FROM TableB tb
        inner join TableC tc
            on tb.fkC = tc.ID
        ) tj
    on tj.NewNames = ta.Filename
```

Here's what I currently have my Linq query looking like, but I know it's not correct.
LINQ:

```
var query = (from ta in ef.TableA
             where (from tb in ef.TableB
                    from tc in ef.TableC
                        .Where(tc => tc.ID == tb.fkC)
                    select new { NewNames = tb.StringField ?? SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tc.IntField) + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tb.IntField2)}
                    ).Contains(ta.Filename)
             select ta.Filename
            ).Distinct().OrderBy(ta => ta.Filename).ToList();
```

It complains about the `Contains` because of the anonymous type created in the subquery. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: how about using `LIKE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `Any` extension method:

```
var query = (from ta in ef.TableA
             where (from tb in ef.TableB
                    from tc in ef.TableC
                        .Where(tc => tc.ID == tb.fkC)
                    select new { NewNames = tb.StringField ?? SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tc.IntField) + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tb.IntField2)}
                    ).Any(e.NewNames==ta.Filename)
             select ta.Filename
            ).Distinct().OrderBy(ta => ta.Filename).ToList();
```

Or you can project your inner query just using the string you get after the concatenation operation:

```
var query = (from ta in ef.TableA
             where (from tb in ef.TableB
                    from tc in ef.TableC
                        .Where(tc => tc.ID == tb.fkC)
                    select  (tb.StringField ?? SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tc.IntField) + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tb.IntField2))
                    ).Contains(ta.Filename)
             select ta.Filename
            ).Distinct().OrderBy(ta => ta.Filename).ToList();
```

### Update

I think the following can improve a little bit your query:

```
var query = (from ta in ef.TableA
             where (from tb in ef.TableB
                    join tc in ef.TableC on tb.fkC equals tc.Id
                    where (tb.StringField ?? SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tc.IntField) + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tb.IntField2))==ta.Filename
                    select tb).Any()
             select ta.Filename
            ).Distinct().OrderBy(ta => ta.Filename).ToList();
```

Comment: I still received an error with the `Any`, but the second method seems like it would probably work. However, I'm getting timeout errors because the tables are large and it's not creating an efficient query. It ends up doing a subquery that selects everything from TableA, which has a lot of records. It still does this even if I flip the query around and start with TableB (B join C join A) and just join on StringField = Filename (ignoring possible NULL cases).

Comment: @wham12,  I have added a new query trying to improve the efficiency. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sadly it still does a full select of TableA as a subquery. I think I'm just going to have to save my SQL query as a stored procedure and call it via EF.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good idea, with a SP you can also avoid to use `SqlFunctions`, which can also affect the performance.